# Aplicativo para fazer ligaçoes de emergencia

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou tentando fazer com q o meu aplicativo faça uma ligação de emergencia ao clicar no botão, porem ao executar ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

ERRO:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.matheus.privatewalletm, PID: 28931
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.matheus.privatewalletm/com.example.matheus.privatewalletm.Ligacao}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
at com.example.matheus.privatewalletm.Main.abreEmergencia(Main.java:53)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Classe de ligação

```
package com.example.matheus.privatewalletm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Ligacao extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    String telefone = "190";
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + telefone);
    Intent intencao = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
    startActivity(intencao);

    }
}
```

XML de ligação

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ligar Emergencia"
        android:id="@+id/buttonLigar"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.matheus.privatewalletm.Main"
    android:onClick="abreMenu">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonNovo"
        android:background="@drawable/pwnovo50x50"
        android:onClick="abreNovo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonMenu"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonLista"
        android:background="@drawable/lista2"
        android:onClick="abreLista"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMenu"
        android:background="@drawable/menu50x50"
        android:onClick="abreMenu"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonLista"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
        android:background="@drawable/pwburnerlogo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Para começar a ultizar o faça o cadastro das suas informações no ícone a baixo"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton10"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:background="@drawable/seta3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton10"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonNovo"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonNovo"
        android:background="@drawable/emergencia50x50"
        android:onClick="abreEmergencia"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main class

```
package com.example.matheus.privatewalletm;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button buttonFazerLigacao;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public void abreLista(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Lista.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void abreNovo(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Novo.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void abreMenu(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void abreEmergencia(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Ligacao.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.matheus.privatewalletm/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.matheus.privatewalletm/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Comment: Formate o código da pergunta.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problema no OnClick, não consigo passar as informaçoes do Array pra uma text view](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152463/problema-no-onclick-n%c3%a3o-consigo-passar-as-informa%c3%a7oes-do-array-pra-uma-text-vie)

Comment: Você duplicou a pergunta? Alias, o problema é em outro lugar, mas a solução é a mesma da sua outra pergunta.

Comment: @Bacco O erro aqui é outro, é questão de não declarar a Activity no Manifest. Essa possível duplicada é erro está na permissão. Talvez não obtiveram sucesso na elaboração das perguntas.

Comment: @seamusd na verdade tem uma série delas com problemas diversos, isso que é pior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Você não declarou a activity **Ligacao** no AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: +1 pela observação. A princípio o erro é esse, porém daqui a pouco ele vai deparar com a questão de permissão Android 6.0. Só escreve! =)